# How to change css of class default in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a tag div:

`class="ant-upload ant-upload-select ant-upload-select-picture-card"`

I tried many ways but can't change the style of tag div.
Thanks for watching!

[image: 1]

Comment: what did you try to do? How did you change styles?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default style by adding your custom style. For example, if you want to change the background color, add new CSS class in your custom CSS file as,

```
.ant-upload.ant-upload-select-picture-card{
     background-color: 'red';
}
```